# HttpMessageHandler vs DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The `DelegatingHandler` inherit from `HttpMessageHandler`. But, I didn't understand the difference, given that you must implement the same method, `SendAsync` to make both work.

What's the difference between this two Handlers? When should I use each one?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are familiar with ASP.NET, then a good analogy will be HTTP handlers and modules. If you implement an `HttpMessageHandler`, you implement the `Send` and `SendAsync` methods and return a response or promise of a response. This is similar to an Http handler. If you implement a `DelegatingHandler` and add it to the `config.MessageHandlers` collection, your class runs in the pipeline and gets an opportunity to see and react to the request and responses, just like an HTTP module. `DelegatingHandler` is also an `HttpMessageHandler` except that as part of `SendAsync` implementation, it just calls the `SendAsync` of the inner handler. The inner handler will do the same and you get the Chinese boxes or the Russian dolls effect. `HttpServer`, where the pipeline starts is itself a `DelegatingHandler`.

Comment: Does anyone know how to configure message handlers in web.config

Comment: is it possible to perform redirects within a DelegatingHandler? Kindly if you know it's capabilities please response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423646/validating-request-in-delegatinghandler-and-redirects

Answer (score 4):

The difference is very subtle. @Badri gave you a good quick explanation.

Looking [at this poster](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf), you realize what it is all about. Keep in mind that when you create your own DelegatingHandlers, you don't mess around with anything that is not specifically HTTP stuff. That's not the place for playing with the BODY in the case of a POST. for example.

One useful thing you can do is to detect very early in the pipe that a token is not present in the headers, then you can terminate right then and there the request and create a StatusCode.Forbidden response. Of course, maybe a simple website doesn't need it. Just an overkill. But if you are receiving millions of calls a minute, it comes very handy since it happens right before the controller is actually instantiated.

There are only a few of cases where you really are going to need that. Or say that the client making the rest call, can only make GET and POST but in the headers it's specifying a X-Method-Override = PUT, then you can at this point modify the request method from POST to PUT, so that your controller/action dispatchers creates the right instance and call the right action.

Here is the interesting poster. PRINT IT :D

http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf

Comment: 7 years later, thanks Pepito, this poster is great succinct work! Looking for an up-to-date version although I don't think much had changed.